# Standard Report Functionality - Is it possible to filter by formula

Tags: apex, visualforce, reporting, filters

Looking at the standard report functionality, it seems not to be possible to filter by formulas defined in the report itself (I don't mean formula fields defined on the object).

Is this really not possible?

Any workarounds?

Comment: You are correct. If you need to filter by the formula then you will have to define it on the object so the field exists to filter on. Formulas are evaluated on running the report so not sure it would be possible to filter on them unless they added a second pass or something to the report generation. Maybe someone else has a better workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't compare fields to fields in report filters.  However, depending on exactly what you need to compare, you could approach this by way of a Visualforce page that feeds filter values to the report via URL.

So if the value you want to use in the report isn't available as a field in your report type, create a VF page and controller that queries the db in the controller constructor, does any needed computation, and holds the value available for the page.  A commandlink can then be used to pass that value (or values) to the report.

There are three classes of parameter you can pass to a report

- pv0 = report filter value
- pn0 = report filter comparison operator
- pc0 = report filter field

For all of these, zero indicates the first report filter.  To work with the second report filter, use pv1 etc.

Read more on passing report parameters [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=906F00000008q0sIAA).

I've been able to use pv0 and pn0 successfully.  I've had trouble with pc0.  Possibly I was trying to do something too tricky (maybe a field from a related object).

Note: according to what others have said, this parameter passing won't work for joined reports.